# Qt Drag'n'Drop application window(s) – similar to browser tabs

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

The task at hand is implementing a drag and drop handler that allows to drag an element either

- between windows
- outside a window

The desired behavior is like that of browser tabs: By pulling a tab from one browser window to another the tab can be moved between the windows. Pulling the tab out of a window creates a new browser window with that tab opened.

I'd like to replicate this in my program.

I see several possibilities implementing this manually, however is there some easy way to implement this with the batteries included in Qt?

Comment: None of the browsers I have installed use D+D for this.  Simple mouse capture, moving a window around on the mouse-move notification.

Comment: @HansPassant: That'd be the way I've implemented it as well. I was just wondering if I could have somehow hijacked QDrag for this (it has to do all that heavy lifting, i.e. creating a window for the pixmap, mouse capture and so on…). Oh well, there goes my afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

afaik there is no such 'one-liner' to get this behaviour.

one approach would be that your application stores all needed information about the tab in the clipboard, and knows how to interpret this information to create the new tab (in the 2nd instance).

another approach would be (when i think of firefox, but i dont know how they handle it) to use shared memory and share this pointer between your instances (but i do not know if this is considered 'safe')

cheers

Comment: Browsers usually share a single instance process for the window, so there's actually no need for IPC to do this. In my case things are limited to the particular process in question anyway, so no need to fiddle around with IPC mechanisms as well. I was just curious if I could piggyback on the existing mouse-capture and window-for-pixmap dragging already implemented for QDrag for this.